# implement stop and snooze for Android alarm

Tags: android, media-player, alarmmanager, alarm

I hope to set up an Android alarm for two time span everyday, for example, 8am--9am, 12pm--13pm. For each time span, it rings every 5 minutes. When press the "snooze", it finish the current activity, and rings at the next time interval (in 5 minutes); when press the "stop", it finish the current activity, and rings at the next time span (to the beginning of 12pm--13pm).

I finish the "snooze", but haven't figured out how to jump into the next time span for "stop".  How can I pass the return value when I click the button, so the AlarmManager can know the difference and cancel the next alarm?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to set the alarms and other relevant code. It is impossible to answer your question without seeing how you are already doing things.